# Increase WiFi signal reach with a WiFi adapter with a strong antenna

Tags: wireless-networking

Can I increase my computer WiFi signal reach by buying a WiFi adapter with a strong antenna?
I'm looking to access far access points.

Comment: Yes... Repeater units are readily available - but DO NOT (please) use ethernet-over-mains

Answer (score 1):

How far is far? The [WiFi extender](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_c_0_10?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=wifi%20extender&sprefix=wifi%20exten%2Caps%2C375) should have at least 70% signal from the access point, because the WiFi extender does not make the signal better, it just makes it longer. So if the extender has a far/slow connection, so does everything connected to the extender. Also, the extender should not be to close to the access point, because then the devices connected to the extender have a bad connection to the extender.

Also, if the access point is in the same building as the device connecting to it, and both the access point and the device have a open ethernet port, I would recommend using [ethernet powerline adapters](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_c_0_14?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=ethernet%20powerline%20adapter&sprefix=ethernet%20power%2Caps%2C252&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Aethernet%20powerline%20adapter). This carries the signal from your router, into your powerline, into the device. This gives the device a strong ranged connected. How ever, the device must always be connected to the adapter with an ethernet cable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can obtain a "stronger" antenna to put on your wifi adapter and this can be used to connect to access points that are a long way away or have a weak signal.

Only certain adapters have a socket for an antenna but if they do you can buy a range of antennas to fit in them.

Antennas are defined by the relative antenna power gain, usually measured in dBi. This figure is broadly the power of the antenna relative to a perfect point source transmitting in a sphere. 3 dBi translates roughly to be a doubling of power.

There is no magic source of power, though. Broadly speaking, the antenna focuses the power into a narrower beam (relative to a sphere). At an extreme, a yagi antenna can focus the beam into a very narrow beam and carry the signal a very long way.